# MYSQL SUM 2 values in a CASE statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I've got the following query

```
SELECT 
ORG.`id`,

ORG.`organisation_name`,

SFCR.report_date_year 

,CASE 
    -- GWP
    WHEN (QRT_VALUES.`template_id` = 'S.05.01.02.01' AND QRT_VALUES.`row_id` = 'R0110' AND QRT_VALUES.`column_id` = 'C0200') THEN 'gross_written_premiums' 

    WHEN (QRT_VALUES.`template_id` = 'S.05.01.02.02' AND QRT_VALUES.`row_id` = 'R1410' AND QRT_VALUES.`column_id` = 'C0300') THEN 'gross_written_premiums' 

END AS Dimension 
,CASE
    -- GWP
    WHEN (QRT_VALUES.`template_id` = 'S.05.01.02.01' AND QRT_VALUES.`row_id` = 'R0110' AND QRT_VALUES.`column_id` = 'C0200' || 
          QRT_VALUES.`template_id` = 'S.05.01.02.02' AND QRT_VALUES.`row_id` = 'R1410' AND QRT_VALUES.`column_id` = 'C0300') 
    THEN  
        (
            (CASE 
                WHEN (QRT_VALUES.`template_id` = 'S.05.01.02.01' AND QRT_VALUES.`row_id` = 'R0110' AND QRT_VALUES.`column_id` = 'C0200') 
                THEN (QRT_VALUES.`value`) ELSE 0 END)
            +

            (CASE 
                WHEN (QRT_VALUES.`template_id` = 'S.05.01.02.02' AND QRT_VALUES.`row_id` = 'R1410' AND QRT_VALUES.`column_id` = 'C0300') 
                THEN (QRT_VALUES.`value`) ELSE 0 END)
        )

END AS Value,  

ORG.`parent_id` AS `parent_id`

FROM ird_qrt_values AS QRT_VALUES

LEFT JOIN `ird_reports` AS SFCR ON (QRT_VALUES.`report_id` = SFCR.`id` AND SFCR.`report_type_id` = 1)

LEFT JOIN `ird_organisations` AS ORG ON (SFCR.`organisation_id` = ORG.`id` AND SFCR.`report_type_id` = 1)

WHERE 
-- GWP
(QRT_VALUES.`template_id` = 'S.05.01.02.01' AND QRT_VALUES.`row_id` = 'R0110' AND QRT_VALUES.`column_id` = 'C0200') OR

(QRT_VALUES.`template_id` = 'S.05.01.02.02' AND QRT_VALUES.`row_id` = 'R1410' AND QRT_VALUES.`column_id` = 'C0300') AND 
SFCR.`qrt_processed` = 1 

HAVING organisation_name = 'Aviva Plc';
```

Currently this query produces the following result

```
id      organisation_name       report_date_year        Dimension                       Value
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
351     Aviva Plc               2016                    gross_written_premiums          15672717.000
351     Aviva Plc               2016                    gross_written_premiums          9708280.000
351     Aviva Plc               2017                    gross_written_premiums          8234725.034
351     Aviva Plc               2017                    gross_written_premiums          9150979.428
```

What i am looking for is the SUM of the 2 numbers as one row for each year. See below table. I am not sure how to do this within the case statement.

```
id      organisation_name       report_date_year        Dimension                       Value
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
351     Aviva Plc               2016                    gross_written_premiums          25380997.000
351     Aviva Plc               2017                    gross_written_premiums          17385704.462
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can wrap it with an outer query and use sum(value) group by ...

Comment: It seems very strange to me to using a `HAVING` and `WHERE` clause together without `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Normally, whenever you use a `CASE` construct you would include an `ELSE`. Not sure this is the issue but I would start by properly ending them.

Comment: hi guys thanks for getting back on this, @isaace, it would be great if you could show how i wrap it in outer query? i've tried that i reckon but may be done something different. thanks again.

Comment: Looking at that query, no need to wrap another query around the outside. A SUM() can be used around the CASE that generates the value column. Just add a group by clause at the end for all the other columns. I agree with @TimBiegeleisen , the HAVING clause is a bit odd. Seems probable that it can be changed to part of the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, organisation_name, report_date_year, Dimension, SUM(Value) Value
FROM
(<Your current Query>) t
GROUP BY
id, organisation_name, report_date_year, Dimension
```